# Compile regex only once and cleanup on program exit

Tags: c, global

I have a C function that accepts a string as input and parses as a URI.

This function calls `regcomp` and `regfree` every time it is called for a regex pattern that never changes:

```
#define URI_REGEX_STR \
    "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?"

int
LSUP_term_init(
        LSUP_Term *term, LSUP_term_type type,
        char *data, char *datatype, char *lang)
{

    term->type = type;
    if (data == NULL) return -1;

    if (term->type == LSUP_TERM_URI) {
        // TODO Move this to a code block that is only executed once.
        regex_t ptn;
        int status = regcomp(&ptn, URI_REGEX_STR, REG_EXTENDED);
        assert(status == 0);

        status = regexec(&ptn, data, 0, NULL, 0);
        regfree(&ptn);
        if (status != 0) {
            printf("Error matching URI pattern.\n");

            return(-1);
        }
    }
    // [...]
    return 0;
}
```

This function gets called a lot, and the regex compilation overhead takes a good part of the runtime.

My goal is to:

- Have `ptn` compiled only once
- Have it available for the whole life of the program
- Have it cleaned up properly on exit (this code may be used as a library)

The only solution I have found so far is to create an "environment" struct that gets initialized and torn down by `main` or the code using the library. This, however, seems cumbersome because I have to pass the "environment" pointer to all the functions that need something from it.

Is there a better way to achieve this in C? Such as a global variable that gets freed on exit? (I know that when the program terminates it gets freed anyway, but I'm aware that it is bad practice and besides it messes up my valgrind output ).

Thanks.

Comment: Great, that's just what I was looking for. Can you post a reply so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard C library provides a function called `atexit()`. You can use that to register a handler to free the regex when the program ends.